# NullReferenceException when setting a ToolStripProgressBar's Value

Tags: c#, winforms, progress-bar

I encountered the following issue that occurs when using a `ToolStripProgressBar` (but it doesn't occur when using a `ProgressBar`).

I have a default `Form` with a `StatusStrip`, and on the `StatusStrip` is a `ToolStripProgressBar` named `toolStripProgressBar1`. I have a `FormClosing` event handler. The following code throws a `NullReferenceException` on the line `toolStripProgressBar1.Value = i;` when I close the form:

```cs
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Progress<int> testProgress;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        testProgress = new Progress<int>(i =>
        {
            toolStripProgressBar1.Value = i;
        });
    }

    private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        ((IProgress<int>)testProgress).Report(5);
    }
}
```

According to the debugger, `toolStripProgressBar1` is not `null` at the time of the exception, however many of its fields and properties are `null` for reasons I can't conceive. Can anyone tell me why I get this exception?

Comment: Given that you are in `Closing` I would suspect the framework has started to clean up the UI objects, leading to the unexpected nulls. Hard to say for sure though.

Answer (score 1):

The wrapped progress bar control of the tooltrip progress bar ([`ToolStripProgressBar.ProgressBar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripprogressbar.progressbar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property) has already been disposed when the value is set. This happens not only when action is invoked on handling `FormClosing`, but also on overriding `OnFormClosing`.